# Melt a dataframe by different column names

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
a <- data.frame(list(X1=c("stn", "s1", "stn", "s2"), 
  X2=c("var1", "1", "var4", "2"), 
  X3=c("var2", "2", "var3", "3"), 
  X4=c("NA", "NA", "var2", "2")))
```

```
   X1   X2   X3   X4
1 stn var1 var2   NA
2  s1    1    2   NA
3 stn var4 var3 var2
4  s2    2    3    2
```

How can I get the result:

```r
b <- data.frame(list(stn=c("s1", "s2"), 
  var1=c(1, NA), 
  var2=c(2, 2), 
  var3=c(NA, 3), 
  var4=c(NA, 2)))
```

```
   stn var1 var2 var3 var4
1  s1    1    2   NA   NA
2  s2   NA    2    3    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  group_by(grp = rep(1:2, each = 2)) %>%
  group_map(~ setNames(.x[-1, ], .x[1, ])) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  mutate(across(var1:var3, as.numeric))

# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#   stn    var1  var2  var4  var3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 s1        1     2    NA    NA
# 2 s2       NA     2     2     3
```

Comment: Great - Now I wonder how to convert the columns var1:var3 to numeric: mutate(across(var1:var3, as.numeric)) doesn't convert types.

Comment: @MPB_2022 your code works fine for me. It converts `var1:var3` to numeric successfully. See my update!

Comment: Thanks! Strange - after reloading RStudio it works

Comment: @DarrenTsai, could you please let me know if for each group `group_map(~ setNames(.x[-1, ], .x[1, ]))` the `setNames` part takes out first row out of data and assigns the same row as the column names?

Comment: @KarthikS Yes it does.

Answer (score 4):

A (mostly) base R solution could be split the data.frame and call `janitor::row_to_names(1)` on each split data.frame, recombine it and remove bad columns using `subset`

```
 do.call(dplyr::bind_rows,
        df |> 
  split(cumsum(df$X1 == "stn")) |> 
  lapply(\(x) x |> 
           janitor::row_to_names(1))
  ) |> 
  subset(, -`NA`)

  stn var1 var2 var4 var3
1  s1    1    2 <NA> <NA>
2  s2 <NA>    2    2    3
```